flutter 3.0.0 or higher error: unable to find git in your path
If I install flutter 3.0.0 or later
error: unable to find git in your path
Error pops up
if I install a version less than that, the error does not appear.
What kind of problem?
I've tried adding this and that to the system environment variable and it won't solve it.

what is the git executable file path?

The path is "C:\Program Files\Git"

is it what where git command says?

The path of the git executable is "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe".

so C:\Program Files\Git\bin is not in your Path environment variable

Does that mean I can add the route you mentioned to the environmental variable?
